# highcharts Line color in the chart, in the legend and in the tooltip do not match

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I hope someone here can help me.
I have a chart with multiple y-axes.
I can adjust most colors.
Only the color in the legend and in the tooltip does not match the line color.
The line color and the color of the axis is green. However, the color in the legend and in the tooltip is blue.
Can someone write me where I can set this color?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHIxR.jpg)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getDataRows', function(proceed, multiLevelHeaders) {
      var rows = proceed.call(this, multiLevelHeaders);
      rows = rows.map(row => {
        if (row.x) {
          row[0] = H.dateFormat('%d.%m.%Y', row.x);
        }
        return row;
      });

      return rows;
    });
  }(Highcharts));

  Highcharts.chart('container', {

      chart: {
              zoomType: 'x',
              scrollablePlotArea: {
                  minWidth: 600,
                  scrollPositionX: 1
              }
          },
      title: {
          text: ''
      },

      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
              format: '{value:%d.%m.%Y}'
                    }
      },

      yAxis: [{ //Betriebstunden
          labels: {
              format: '{value} h',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
              }
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Betriebsstunden',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
              }
          },
          opposite: true
      }, { //Temperatur MIN, MAX
          title: {
              text: 'Temperatur Bereich',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
          },
          labels: {
              format: '{value} °C',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
          }
      }, { //Delta
          title: {
              text: 'Temperatur Delta',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
              }
          },
          labels: {
              format: '{value} °C',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4]
              }
          }
      }, { //Drehzahl
          title: {
              text: 'Max. Drehzahl',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6]
              }
          },
          labels: {
              format: '{value} %',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6]
              }
          },
          opposite: true
      }],


      tooltip: {
          xDateFormat: '%d.%m.%Y',
          crosshairs: true,
          shared: true
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Betriebsstunden',
          data: <?php echo chartDataTimeDate($mysqli, $sqlBS) ?>,
          type: 'spline',
          line: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
          },
          tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' h',
          },
          lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
          lineWidth: 3,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
      }, {
          name: 'Temperatur',
          data: <?php echo chartDataTimeDate($mysqli, $sqlTemp) ?>,
          type: 'arearange',
          yAxis: 1,
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
          marker: {
              enabled: false
          }
      },{
          name: 'Temperatur Delta',
          data: <?php echo chartDataTimeDate($mysqli, $sqlDelta) ?>,
          type: 'spline',
          yAxis: 2,
          tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' °C'
          },
          Color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],
          lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[4],
          lineWidth: 3,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
            } 
      },{
          name: 'Drehzahl',
          data: <?php echo chartDataTimeDate($mysqli, $sqlDZ) ?>,
          type: 'spline',
          yAxis: 3,
          tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' %'
          },
          Color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],
          lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6],
          lineWidth: 3,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
            } 
      }]
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `series.color` instead of `series.line.color`:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Betriebsstunden',
    type: 'spline',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
    ...
  }, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mx8fsbaz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color